# Get access token in Python like in Postman

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0, postman

I try to request an access token via Python that is required to interact with an API. I used the program "Postman" to get an idea of that process, see here:
http://api.sharefile.com/rest/index/postman.aspx

Postman has the option to get authorization by requesting an access code (OAuth 2.0) under the 'Authorization'-Tab. After I entered all needed information and hitting the "Request Token"-Button, I am redirected to a website where I want to use the API. It looks like this window: http://api.sharefile.com/rest/oauth2.aspx

After login in, Postman returns a window with the access token.

I now want to perform these actions in Python, but as far as I can see, there seems to be no solution for a web-based login authentication.

With a code like this [(Link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203351/rauth2-decoder-failed-to-handle-access-token-when-i-tried-to-connect-with-box-co) I am able to send a request to the server, but I am not able to request a website, where I can enter my login data.

So is it possible to perform the same actions of Postman in Python? And if it is possible, is it possible to enter the login credentials automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I found out, that I am able to refresh the access token via oauth. So initially I use Selenium to get the access token for the first time via oauth2's login page, simulating a human. When I got the key, I refresh it when the key expires.

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests

client_id = 'xxx'

client_secret = 'xxx'

# scope = f'api://{client_id}/user.access'
scope = f'api://{client_id}/.default'

token_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/token'

d = {
    "client_id": client_id,
    "scope": scope,
    "client_secret": client_secret,
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
}

r = requests.post(token_url, data=d)

access_token = r.json()['access_token']
```